# How to make TOC display the count in word?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I have a document with many figures and tables in it. I want to make a table of figures that will only give me the count for each group found (tables, figures etc.).

I looked this up but did not find any reference on how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are inserting captions for your figures, tables etc., using the standard facilities in Word, then one way to do this would be to add a { TC } field for each group at the end of the document, and insert a TOC field to build a TOC from those fields. e.g.

```
{ TOC \f fc }

{ TC "Number of figures: { SEQ Figure \c }" \f fc \n }
{ TC "Number of tables: { SEQ Table \c }" \f fc \n }
```

and so on.

(All the {} have to be the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word. You will also need to select and update the TC fields before updating the TOC field.)

Comment: Using CTRL+F9, whenever I write TC the whole line dissapears. It's still there but I can't see it anymore.

Comment: Yes, it's because TC fields are hidden, so you have to ensure that hidden text is displayed - probably enough to click the "reveal formatting" button, otherwise look in Word options.

Comment: It can be shown using the Show/Hide button (shortcut CTRL + *). Thank you so much for your help.